# Read data from Usb in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I wanna read data from USB using qt though I have read that it can be done using folderlistmodel but I don't know so may be someone can help me with that.

Comment: USB doesn't work like that. The OS is in control of all devices connected to the USB port, and arranges the communication to them. Applications interface with the OS abstractions of such devices (e.g. USB keyboard, USB mouse, USB disk).

Comment: [How to Access a USB Device by Using WinUSB Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/hardware/ff540174(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Actually, i am using Linux so winusb won't help me.

Comment: **qt/qt4 <> qtp**. Correct the tags to focus on correct audiences.

Answer (score 1):

This is a helpful link on getting raw data(link below).

@MSalter It works exactly like reading from a file or more precisely a buffer. If the OS managed everything within the context of not having access, then every USB device would have to be approved by the OS manufacture which is not the case. (Devices certified by Microsoft or Apple/Mac is not the same as access restrictions to reading/writing to a device).

Reference:
https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41668-Reading-data-from-usb-port